# Exchange EWS ChangeType always "Created"

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, changetype

We are working on synchronizing our outlook-calendar with our custom web application. 
We have set up an exchange-server for testing and we are able to get the calendar-items out of the calender. 
The problem is that the `ChangeType` is always "Created" (although we changed some-values with the outlook-Client from Microsoft).

The code to get the items is the following:

```
ChangeCollection<ItemChange> calendarChangeItems = 
service.SyncFolderItems(folderId, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties, null,512, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, null);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link helps me to understand the meaning of SyncFolderItems:

[How to get required attendees in SyncFolderItems method](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/ab5b2c0f-20b2-4751-a930-824f8b56d3b9/how-to-get-required-attendees-in-syncfolderitems-method?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Very important is to keep the SyncState for further synchronisations. 
Thank you for help.